# How do I find which of 2 values are closer to a given number in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, integer

I have 2 variables, value1 and value2. I want to see which of these values are closer to the number 21 through an if statement. So in pseudocode,

```
If value1 is closer to 21:
    Event1
elif value2 is closer to 21:
    Event2
else:
    Event3
```

Comment: Hint: you can use the `abs()` absolute value function.

Comment: Think of how you would solve it without a computer. Then put that into code.

Comment: Think how you would express this in mathematical terms. What means "closer to a number" mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the absolute value function and see which difference is greater between 21 and the values:

```
value1 = 40
value2 = 8

if abs(21 - value1) < abs(21 - value2):
  print('value1 is closer')
else:
  print('value2 is closer')
```

Output:

```
value2 is closer
```

Think about how you would do it normally. You would find the POSITIVE difference between the two values, and see which is smaller!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def foo(number,val1,val2):
   if abs(number-val1) < abs(number-val2):
      event1()
   elif abs(number-val1)>abs(number-val2):
      event2()
   else:
      event3()
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this example to check which number is closer:

```
#Setting variables
val1 = 2
val2 = 1
cond = 21

check1 = val1
check2 = val2

#arrays to save numbers between
arr1 = []
arr2 = []

#Conditioning values

#Value 1 check

if(check1 > cond):
    while check1 > cond:
        # print(check1)
        arr1.append(check1)
        check1 -= 1
elif(check1 == cond):
    arr1 = [cond]

else:
    while check1 < cond:
        # print(check1)
        arr1.append(check1)
        check1 += 1

#Value 2 check

if(check2 > cond):
    while check2 > cond:
        # print(check2)
        arr2.append(check2)
        check2 -= 1
elif(check2 == cond):
    arr2 = [cond]

else:
    while check2 < cond:
        # print(check2)
        arr2.append(check2)
        check2 += 1

result1 = len(arr1)
result2 = len(arr2)
# Checking which value is closer
if(result1 == result2):
    print('Both numbers are equaly closer')

elif(result1 < result2):
    print(f'The number {val1} is closer to {cond}')

else:
    print(f'The number {val2} is closer to {cond}')
```